# Is a Markov process uniquely determined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be a Polish space and $\mathcal E$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$
- $I\subseteq[0,\infty)$ be closed under addition and $0\in I$

Please consider the following result:

> Let $(\kappa_t:t\in I)$ be a Markovian semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$ $\Rightarrow$ There is a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and a Markov process $X$ with distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ such that $$\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in B\right]=\kappa_t(x,B)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E,B\in\mathcal E\text{ and }t\in I\;.\tag 1$$ Conversely, given a Markov process $X$ with distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, a Markovian semigroup $(\kappa_t:t\in I)$ is defined by $(1)$.

It turns out that $X$ in the first part of the statement can be constructed as the family of coordinate maps on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)=(E^I,\mathcal E^{\otimes I})$.

I've seen that many authors assume that Markov processes are such coordinate maps. Why can they do that?

The statement above doesn't state, that given $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ there is one unique Markov process, does it? However, the finite-dimensional distributions of $X$, i.e. $$\operatorname P_x\left[X\in\;\cdot\;\right]\circ\pi_J^{-1}\;\;\;\text{for }J\subseteq I\text{ with }|J|<\infty\;,\tag 2$$ where $\pi_J:E^I\to E^J$ are the canonical projections, are uniquely determined by $(1)$.

Maybe $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ (not only the finite-dimensional distributions) are uniquely determined by $(1)$, if $I\subseteq \mathbb N_0$ or $I$ is at least almost countable or when $E$ is almost countable.

So, why does the stated result allows us to think about $X$ as being uniquely determined?

Comment: Hint: Kolmogorov extension theorem.

Comment: @Did The extension theorem should only yield, that the *finite-dimensional* distributions of $X$ are uniquely determined. Could you explain in more detail what you've got in mind.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what you are actually asking. In the result stated in your question,there is no mention of "uniqueness". Therefore, your question (at the end) doesn't make sense to me .... could you please clarfiy which kind of uniqueness you are talking about?

Comment: It does not matter if $I$ is countable or not. If it's not, then anyway the elements of $\mathcal{E}^{\otimes I}$ are sets from $\mathcal{E}^{\otimes\mathbb N}$ sitting on some countable sets taken from $I$. So the distribution of $X$ on $(E^I, \mathcal{E}^{\otimes I})$ is always uniquely determined, as in the countable case.

Comment: "The extension theorem should only yield, that the finite-dimensional distributions of XX are uniquely determined." Absolutely not. I suggest to review what the theorem is actually saying (especially when some commenter points you at it, if I may add).

Answer (score 4):

The [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) states that there is a probability distribution on $(E^I, \mathcal E^{\otimes I})$ such that $(1)$ holds.

I claim that this distribution is uniquely determined.

There are two ways to see this, both appealing to the definition of $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$. In fact, it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylindrical sets (equivalently, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra under which each evaluation $f\mapsto f(t)$, $t\in I$, is measurable), that is,
$$\mathcal E^{\otimes I} = \sigma(\mathcal P),\text{ where } \mathcal P = \big\{\{f:f(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in B\}, B\in \mathcal E^{\otimes n}, t_1,\dots,t_n\in I, n\ge 1\big\}.$$

Method 1. One of useful consequences of Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem is the following [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system#Example): if two probabilistic measures coincide on a $\pi$-system, then they coincide on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by this system. Now notice that $\mathcal P$ is obviously a $\pi$-system. Therefore, two measures agreeing on $\mathcal P$ (= two distributions of processes having same finite-dimensional distributions) agree on $\sigma(\mathcal P) = \mathcal E^{\otimes I}$.

Method 2. A slightly extended version of my comment. The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$ has a *countable* description: 
$$
\mathcal E^{\otimes I} = \big\{\{f:f(t_1,t_2,\dots)\in B\}, B\in \mathcal E^{\otimes \mathbb{N}}, t_1,t_2,\dots\in I\big\}.
$$
In other words, each set from $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$ sits on a countable number of coordinates from $I$. But it is not hard to see (as you correctly noted) that for a countable number of coordinates, the distribution is unique. Therefore, it is unique on $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$.